# DC/OS JMX Access to java application

Tags: java, azure, docker, jmx, dcos

I'm new to docker and dc/os. I have deployed dc/os cluster in the microsoft azure. I need to set access via a jmx to my java applications but I can't.
Let's take the example of deploying a standart tomcat image.
I have docker installed on my local machine. To run a tomcat container with jmx access I use this command:

```
docker run -e 
     JAVA_OPTS= "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
                -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8081 
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" 
     -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 tomcat:8.0
```

And I can connect to Tomcat via port 8081.

I try to do the same in dc/os cluster. I use the below json configuration to deploy:

```
{
  "id": "/tomcat",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 512,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "tomcat:8.0",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 8080, "containerPort": 8080 },
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 8081, "containerPort": 8081 }
      ]
    }
  },
  "requirePorts": true,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "slave_public"
  ],
  "env": {      
    "JAVA_OPTS": "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.0.4 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8081 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
      "path": "/",
      "portIndex": 0,
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "timeoutSeconds": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

After that I have access to tomcat webconsole but I can't connnect via jmx. 
I tried variouse values for "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname": 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.4( agent ip ), agents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.
Please help me understand what I do wrong.

UPDATE: Thank Walter - MSFT who pointed out a fact which ports are opened by default on azure. I really forgot about it. But an issue with connecting via jmx is still actual for me. I opened new discussion where I give more details. [DC/OS JMX Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372719/dc-os-jmx-access)

Comment: this `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Hi, Robert. How and why could it help? it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read [Azure official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access#open-a-port-portal):

> Any DC/OS container in the ACS public agent pool is automatically
>   exposed to the internet. By default, ports 80, 443, 8080 are opened,
>   and any (public) container listening on those ports are accessible.

According to your description, it seems that port 8081 is not open. You could open port 8081 on Azure Portal.

More information about please refer to this link: [Enable public access to an Azure Container Service application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access#open-a-port-portal).

Update:

I test in my lab with your json file, it works for me, you don't change it. You should open port on Azure NSG and Load Balance.

NSG:
[image]

LoadBalncer[image]

I test in my lab, I could open 8080 Web UI. When I test port 8081, I notice that the port is listening, I could access the port with Public IP.

```
azureuser@dcos-master-01234567-0:~$ netcat -z -v 13.84.176.235 8081
Connection to 13.84.176.235 8081 port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!
```

You also could use curl to test, I get the following result.

```
azureuser@dcos-master-01234567-0:~$ curl 13.84.176.235:8081
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

If you could not access 8081 Web UI, I suggest you had better check docker container.

Comment: @You need set your service is listening on 10.0.0.4, if you use 127.0.0.1, you could not access it on Internet.

Comment: Hi, Walter. Thank you very much for response . I really lost sight of this fact. 
I changed my configuration:
 "portMappings": [
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 80  , "containerPort": 8080 },
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 8080, "containerPort": 8081 }
      ]
But I still can't connect. 10.0.0.4 is ip address of my public agent node.

Comment: "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.0.4"
I connected to master node and executed next commands:
<user>@<master>:~$ netcat -z -v 10.0.0.4 8080
Connection to 10.0.0.4 8080 port [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!
<user>@<master>:~$ netcat -z -v 10.0.0.4 80
Connection to 10.0.0.4 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!

Comment: I executed next commands from my local windows machine:
PS <HOMEPATH>> tnc <prefix>agents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com -Port 80
TcpTestSucceeded       : True
PS C:\Users\turkian2> tnc <prefix>agents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com -Port 8080
TcpTestSucceeded       : True
Everything seems ok but I still can't connect.

Comment: @Andryusha2006 You could not point 8080 to two service on your container. I test in my lab with your json file. I could access 8080 web UI, when I test 8081 using `curl IP:8081` I get the log `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. I also test port 8081 `azureuser@dcos-master-01234567-0:~$ netcat -z -v 10.0.0.4 8081
Connection to 10.0.0.4 8081 port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!
`

Comment: Walter, thank u for your reply. I didn't understand what you meant about pointing 8080 to two services. I mapped ports of my tomcat container 8080 and 8081 to ports 80 and 8080. I have only one deployed service.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.I see wrong. It is 80 not 8080.

Comment: @Could you test `curl 10.0.0.4:8080` on your master VM, I think you will get the same result with me. `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145699/discussion-between-andryusha2006-and-walter-msft).