# DC/OS JMX Access

Tags: java, azure, docker, jmx, dcos

I have a dc/os cluster deployed to azure. I have deployed to the cluster a container with my java application. But I can't access it via jmx.

Let's take the example of deploying a standart tomcat image:

1) I opened a port 8081 according the next instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access#open-a-port-portal.

2) I deployed service using the next json:

```
{
  "id": "/tomcat",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 512,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "tomcat:8.0",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 8080   , "containerPort": 8080 },
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 8081   , "containerPort": 8081 }
      ]
    }
  },
  "requirePorts": true,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "slave_public"
  ],
  "env": {      
    "JAVA_OPTS": "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.0.4 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8081 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
      "path": "/",
      "portIndex": 0,
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "timeoutSeconds": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

To connect I use Oracle Java Mission Control. I fill fields 'Host' and 'Port' as 'prefixagents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com' and '8081'. But I can't connect and I get a message: 'Unable to connect'.

But for all that I can succesfully connect to this port using telnet client:

`telnet prefixagents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com 8081`

Also I can connect to port 8080 and I can open tomcat web console at the following URL: http://agents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8080

I installed one more jmx command line client - http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/ and tried to connect to the service:

```
java -jar jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar  --url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<prefix>agents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8081/jmxrmi
```

I got the next exception: "java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.4". And 10.0.0.4 is hostname of my public agents node.

I connected to my dc/os cluster ( master node ) using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect. I also installed there jmxterm and tried to connect to the service via jmx:

```
java -jar jmxterm.jar --url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.0.0.4:8081/jmxrmi
```

And I connected succesfully.

Does anybody have any ideas why I can connect to the service via jmx from my master node but I can't from my local machine? Port 8081 is opened.

Comment: DC/OS agents ssh service are not exposed to Internet. You could ssh to agents on Master VM. Master node and agent node use the same ssh key. You could copy your private key to master VM.  

    ssh -i <path>/id_rsa user@10.0.0.4

You also could use FileZilla to upload private key to master VM.

Comment: When I `docker exec  -it 3802221a5808 bash`, I find jmx process with `ps -ef|grep jmx`. I get the result `root@3802221a5808:/usr/local/tomcat/bin# ps -ef|grep jmx
root         1     0  4 06:50 ?        00:00:27 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0 -Dcom.sun.managem....
`

Comment: Based on my experience, it seems that your configuration is correct. Could you try deploy your app to tomcat container and test again?

Comment: `Does anybody have any ideas why I can connect to the service via jmx from my master node but I can't from my local machine? Port 8081 is opened.` Do you mean you could access jmx on master VM `curl 10.0.0.4:8081` on master VM?

Comment: Yes, I mean that I can access jmx on master VM. I can't access jmx from my local machine but I can access jmx port using telnet client.

Comment: In master VM, what is the result `curl 10.0.0.4:8081`?

Comment: I suggest you had better check whether you enable jmx on master VM, master VM does not open port 8081.

Comment: curl 10.0.0.4:8081
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: The same result, it seems that you could not access jmx on master VM.

Comment: why? I can connect and I connected using jmx client jmxterm:java -jar jmxterm.jar --url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.0.0.4:8081/jmxrmi
Welcome to JMX terminal. Type "help" for available commands.
$>azureuser@dcos-agent-public-...:~$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145946/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-andryusha2006).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed a value of property -Djava.rmi.server.hostname in JAVA_OPTS string: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname="public agent ip". And it works for me.
Working configuration for a standart tomcat container in case that port 8081 is open:

```
{
  "id": "/tomcat",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 512,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "tomcat:8.0",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 8080   , "containerPort": 8080 },
        { "protocol": "tcp", "hostPort": 8081   , "containerPort": 8081 }
      ]
    }
  },
  "requirePorts": true,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "slave_public"
  ],
  "env": {      
    "JAVA_OPTS": "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public agent ip> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8081 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
      "path": "/",
      "portIndex": 0,
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "timeoutSeconds": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

And I can connect to tomcat via jmx using from local machine: host="public agent ip" and port=8081

public agent ip = "prefix"agents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

Comment: For this approach to work, it's crucial that the port number used inside the container be the same as the port number used on the host (see the `portMappings` array). If those are different, the JMX code will tell the client to connect back on a port that isn't the one the host has exposed, and the connection will fail.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody have any ideas why I can connect to the service via jmx
>   from my master node but I can't from my local machine? Port 8081 is
>   opened.

You should connect jmx as the following command.

```
java -jar jmxterm.jar --url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<agent public IP>:8081/jmxrmi
```

Update:

hostname should be `public agent ip`, then you could connect jmx from your local PC.

Comment: Hi, Walter-MSFT,I don't have problem with connecting to master node and agents node. I can connect to them.I deployed a tomcat container to public node, sshed to master node and in result I could connected to the tomcat via jmx from my master node. But my issue is in connecting to the tomcat via jmx from my local machine( host: prefixagens.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com).JMX port is accessible from internet and I can connect using telnet client.But when I try to connect using jmx client, I get exception: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.4- inner public agent node hostname.